# How to get registryKey name alone instead of full registry keypath?

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-2.0

I was trying to get all the sub registry keys from registry key

```
$Key="hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj"
$ComponentKeys=Get-ChildItem -path $Key 
$ComponentName=$Components | Select-object Name
$ComponentName
```

It displays the result like below

```
Name
----
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\Service
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\UserInterface
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\DataSetView
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\Notification
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\Model
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\Management
```

But I just would like to retrieve the subkey name not the full name.

I need result like below

```
Name
----
Service
UserInterface
DataSetView
Notification
Model
Management
```

How to get the key name alone?

Comment: FYI, that's not a key.  That's a Value Name.  You want the Value name. The key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj\` the value is *service* and the information held by the value is called *data*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
 $ComponentName=$Components | select pschildname
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get it from $ComponentName?

Comment: a little ugly: `$componentName | % { $_.name.split('\') | select -last 1 }`

Answer (score 9):

You can get names only with the Name switch:

```
$Key="hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj"
Get-ChildItem $key -Name
```

If you already have paths in a variable, use the `Split-Path` cmdlet:

```
$componentName | Split-Path -Leaf
```

Comment: My command doesn't use braces, where exactly am I missing it?

Comment: When using the command it show keyname as MyProj}. I don't know why it adds opening and closing braces "{hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyProj}"